# Presenting a viewController on SKScene

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I am trying to present `UIActivityViewController` on an `SkView`  but xcode gives me this error :

> No visible @interface for 'GameOver' declares the selector
>   'presentViewController:animated:completion:'

```
- (void)shareScore {

    //add view
    UIView *Sview  = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 512, 512)];
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shareScoreImg.png"]];
    image.frame = Sview.frame;
    [Sview addSubview:image];

    //add label
    CGRect fframe = self.view.frame;

    UILabel *score = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:fframe];
    score.text = @"9999";
    score.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    score.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    score.center = CGPointMake(250, 440);
    score.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Pixel LCD7" size:50];
    [Sview addSubview:score];


    //capture view
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(Sview.bounds.size, Sview.opaque, 0.0);
    [Sview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[screenshot]
                                      applicationActivities:nil];

    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

How can I present preset a viewController on SKScene ?
thanks .

Comment: You can't, `UIView` or any other view do not have the method `presentViewController: animated:completion:`. That method is only available on `UIViewController`

Comment: @rckoenes So how can I share games's score to Facebook , and etc ... ?!!!!

Comment: Via a ViewController or window.

Comment: @rckoenes I mean in the game !!! which is SKScene

Comment: You don't want to show Share scores button during gameplay, do you? Create a different view with different ViewController for Game Over screen

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We can use "presentModalViewController" by using this code to access the root view controller

```
 UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
    [vc presentViewController: activityViewController animated: YES completion:nil];
```

now it works fine !

Comment: LOL, you've basically used my answer.

Comment: Not really. Since you didn't put any code. Mc.Lover put a code. I like his answer more than yours. LOL?

Comment: This is the answer folks!

Comment: @Paul this will only work if the rootViewController of the window is the uiviewcontroller that contains the skscene. What happens if you use a navcontroller or something else? Then this won't work.

Comment: In fact, this is probably the one way that I wouldn't use. It's so inflexible. It would make much more sense to use either delegation or notifications. Or even just to have a reference back to the uiviewcontroller from the scene. Either of those would be better than this.

Answer (score 6):

IIRC the first `SKScene` that you create is inside an `SKView`.

This `SKView` is inside a `UIViewController`.

You can use properties or delegation or whatever you like to access methods on the `UIViewController` through the `SKView` from the `SKScene`. Or even use a notification.

Then on the `UIViewController` you can present the new view controller with no problems.

Comment: @Mc.Lover it looks like you are trying to present from the `SKView` you still can't do this. You need to present from the `UIViewController`.

Comment: @Paul an answer doesn't necessarily need code. The solution here was the concept of how to present a ViewController from an skscene. The are many ways to do it. Providing code will only ever cover one of those ways and so would actually be a worse answer. As you can see from the fact that the answer was accepted the OP found enough information here to fix his problem.