# Calling presentViewController in main ViewController of SpriteKit Game

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm building "spritekit" game, i need to present another `viewController` than main `viewcontroller`.
I tried to perform this with delegates and with notification center to send ask to present new view controller. Both ways correctly called this function inside main `viewController`(tuViewController)  from "SkScene" (tuGameOver). The point is to correctly present `FacebookLikeViewDemoViewController`

```
-(void)showShareScreen{
    NSLog(@"VIEWCONTROLER RECEIVED");
    FacebookLikeViewDemoViewController *helpVC = [[FacebookLikeViewDemoViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FacebookLikeViewDemoViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController: helpVC animated: YES completion:nil];
}
```

When this function is executed i got `NSlog` and after that `terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` SIGABRT Error.

I also tried to modify this function to :

```
-(void)showShareScreen{
    NSLog(@"VIEWCONTROLER RECEIVED");

    UIViewController *vc = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController;
        FacebookLikeViewDemoViewController *helpVC = [[FacebookLikeViewDemoViewController alloc]init];
    [vc presentViewController: helpVC animated: YES completion:nil];
}
```

And with this, i didn't get crash, and something appears but this is blank black screen.

`FacebookLikeViewDemoViewController`  is typical `viewController` Class, pinned up to view Controller in storyboard.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mc.Lover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319097/mc-lover) (chuckle) came up with a solution for presenting a VC in SKScene. Below is the gist of his solution. I have added it to the touchesBegan: method so you can easily test it.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView *Sview  = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 512, 512)];
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shareScoreImg.png"]];
    image.frame = Sview.frame;
    [Sview addSubview:image];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(Sview.bounds.size, Sview.opaque, 0.0);
    [Sview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[screenshot] applicationActivities:nil];

    UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
    [vc presentViewController: activityViewController animated: YES completion:nil];
}
```

His original Q&A is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089332/presenting-a-viewcontroller-on-skscene).

Comment: I don't know how to use this with my problem, could you show me an example with viewController ? I read q&a you provided but it didn't helps me with figure out with this issue.

Comment: @karek - Don't you want to present Facebook/Twitter in your VC?

Comment: I want to present ViewController in which i have created facebook addon, with FaceBookLikeView component from github.

Comment: @karek - the code I posted takes a snapshot of the screen and presents the activity controller which then gives the user the option to mail, print, tweet, facebook, etc...

Comment: I prefer to stay with my idea( i just need to Like my page from game), i have working Liking code, i just need to present ViewController from SkScene with Notification Center.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
 FacebookLikeViewDemoViewController *helpVC = [[FacebookLikeViewDemoViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FacebookLikeViewDemoViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:helpVC animated:YES] ;
```

Comment: I received Nslog from function, but nothing more happened, there wasn't crash and present viewController

Comment: add a navigationController to your present viewController in the storyboard

Comment: I could not add navigationController to my current main viewController, i only could add navigation bar, which changes nothing.

Comment: @karek could you édit your response with image