# Swift - can't get Game Center to show

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, swift, game-center

I am using this code to get **Game Center** to appear when the user presses a button. I want this to show their high scores on the leaderboard:

```
@IBAction func showScores(x : UIButton) {
    var gameCenterController : GKGameCenterViewController!
    if (gameCenterController != nil) {
        gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self
        self.presentViewController(gameCenterController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

But I get an error on this line:

```
gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self
```

That reads,

```
 Type 'MenuViewController' does not conform to protocol `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate`
```

What am I doing wrong?

How can I implement GameCenter into my game so that users' high scores are added to the leaderboards where they can be viewed by pressing a button?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure to declare that your presenting view controller conforms GKGameCenterControllerDelegate like so:

```
class MenuViewController: GKGameCenterControllerDelegate
```

Then In Swift, add the function below to your MenuViewController:

```
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!)
{
    //code to dismiss your gameCenterViewController
    // for example:
    gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Lastly, be sure that the gameCenterDelegate gets set on your game center view controller before you present it. For example:

```
var gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self
```

Note that the delegate is `gameCenterDelegate` and not just `delegate`.

Also, here is an example on how to show your leaderboard from MenuViewController. (This code would be in MenuViewController):

```
func showLeaderboard()
{
    var gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self

    gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards
    gcViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = "yourleaderboardid"

    self.presentViewController(gcViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I created a new Cocoa Touch class file, called `GameCenterViewController`, of subclass `GKGameCenterViewController`. I then changed the top line from `GKGameCenterViewController` to `GKGameCenterViewControllerDelegate`, like you said in your top line of code. However, this resulted in a lot of errors - the first of which on that line: `"Use of undeclared type 'GKGameCenterViewControllerDelegate'"`. What do i need to do?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how to use the code above. In your original code you had a UIViewController named `MenuViewController`. That is the view controller that you will present the GameCenterViewController from. You don't need to subclass it. The 'MenuViewController` in your example and the `YourViewController` in my example are the same view controller. MenuViewController/YourViewController are the ones that should be adopting the GKGameCenterControllerDelegate protocol.

Comment: I edited my original answer to reflect that YourViewController is the same as MenuViewController from your example.

Comment: I am getting a syntax issue at the last line:
self.presentViewController(gcViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
'MY_SCENE_CLASS' does not have a member named 'presentViewController'

Comment: In this example `MenuViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`. Seems like in your code you are trying to present from a subclass of `SKScene` which does not have the `presentViewController` method. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089332/presenting-a-viewcontroller-on-skscene. Please up-vote answers that are helpful to you.

Comment: Using this code in my case game center is displaying only challenges state and no leaderboard state even when I have used gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards

And if i use gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Default
It is giving me a blank view(Nothing just white rect)

Answer (score 3):

It says you didn't implement the delegate method.

```
// Called when the player is done interacting with the view controller’s content. (required)
- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController
```

then you class may implement like this:

```
class YourViewController : GKGameCenterControllerDelegate
{
    func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!)
    {
        // do somthing
    }
}
```

Comment: That top line is Objective-C isn't it? Is there a Swift equivalent?

Comment: yeah! i just copied from apple document. [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKGameCenterViewControllerDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: is there anything wrong? the code of second block is swift, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to Swift, so I'm finding hard to adjust from Objective-C. What's the Swift equivalent of the top line?

Comment: I just show you the delegate method of GKGameCenterControllerDelegate.  Moreover this method should be implemented by your class like the sample code, it's required according to the apple doc.