# Calling .presenttoViewController in SKScene in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, skscene

I'm making a game with Sprite Kit in Swift. When you die in the game it presents the option to share your score on Twitter, Facebook, etc. But since I'm in a SKScene, it doesn't have the member .presentViewController . I need to present the Twitter compose field, is there any way to do this?

Here's the code:

```
if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter) {
            let tweetviewcontroller = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)

            tweetviewcontroller.setInitialText("I Scored \(score) on Cube Falling")
            self.presentViewController(tweetviewcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to your Twitter account", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
                let settingsURL = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
                if let url = settingsURL {
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
          }
   }))


 self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

 }
```

Here's the error: [image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bcl0.png)

Thanks

Comment: `SKScene` doesn't have a member called 
`presentViewController:animated:completion:` ... That method is a part of `UIViewController` class.

Comment: Yeah I know but is there any way to still execute the presentation ?@Whirlwind

Comment: Have you searched SO ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/21089332/3402095 There are a lot of similar posts to this one.

Comment: All the ones I've tried (In Swift) haven't worked @Whirlwind